# How to perform a reinterpretation cast in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, boxing, reinterpret-cast

I'm working with an old Windows application made in vb.net and trying to open a file downloaded from my firmware but it requires a reinterpretation cast that I'm not sure how to do in vb.net

In my C source I save a double (32-bit) to a file like so:

```
Uint32 pow = *(Uint32*)&(slices[i].power);
Disk.Write.U32(pow);
```

To read the file in the firmware I do this:

```
Uint32 pow = Disk.Read.U32();
slices[i].power = *(double*)&pow;
```

(Uint32 is a typecast for an unsigned long)

I need to replicate that read in the vb.net application but everything I've tried results in an incorrect value. Essentially all I'm doing is saving the raw bit pattern of a 4-byte IEEE floating point value into 4 bytes and then restoring it.

Comment: It sounds like you might need to use the `BitConverter` class.

Comment: Nevermind, I had the wrong endianess, this worked thank you. If you want to submit it as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It's not really specific enough for an answer. You should post your own answer with all the details of the solution.